# Check that both `lookbehind` conditions are satisfied in `RegEx`

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I'm trying to check if a username is preceded either by `RT @` or by `RT@` by using `lookbehind` mechanism paired with conditionals, as explained in [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) tutorial.
The regex and the example are shown in `Example 1`:

**Example 1**

```
import re

text = 'RT @u1, @u2, u3, @u4, rt @u5:, @u3.@u1^, rt@u3'

mt_regex = r'(?i)(?<!RT )&(?<!RT)@(\w+)'

mt_pat = re.compile(mt_regex)

re.findall(mt_pat, text)
```

which outputs `[]` (empty list), while the desired output should be:

```
['u2', 'u4', 'u3', 'u1']
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we break down your regex:

```
r"(?i)(?<!RT )&(?<!RT)@(\w+)"
(?i)        match the remainder of the pattern, case insensitive match
(?<!RT )    negative lookbehind
            asserts that 'RT ' does not match
&           matches the character '&' literally
(?<!RT)     negative lookbehind 
            asserts that 'RT' does not match
@           matches the character '@' literally
(\w+)       Capturing Group    
            matches [a-zA-Z0-9_] between one and unlimited times
```

You have the `&` character that is preventing your regex matching:

```
import re

text = "RT @u1, @u2, u3, @u4, rt @u5:, @u3.@u1^, rt@u3"
mt_regex = r"(?i)(?<!RT )(?<!RT)@(\w+)"
mt_pat = re.compile(mt_regex)

print(re.findall(mt_pat, text))
# ['u2', 'u4', 'u3', 'u1']
```

See this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/5QpPJ2/1)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is obviously correct and rightfully accepted, but here is what I think might work for you without negative lookbehinds. The benefit is that you are not limited to the single space character using `\s*`:

```
(?i)(?:^|[,.])\s*@(\w+)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pbJCut/3)

---

- `(?i)` - Turn of case sensitivity. Note you can also use `re.IGNORECASE`.
- `(?:^|[,.])` - Non-capture group to match start of string or literal comma/dot.
- `\s*` - Zero or more spaces.
- `@` - Literally match "@".
- `(\w+)` - Open capture group and match word characters, short for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

---

This print `['u2', 'u4', 'u3', 'u1']`

Comment: This is a really nice solution!